# Unexpected non-void return value in void function in function that declares an Int return

Tags: swift

I get an error by each return statement saying "Unexpected non-void return value in void function." It's clearly not a void function, so why is it saying it is? When I change the return statement to return void, it says it's looking for an Int. I tried cleaning my project and that didn't fix it. Any ideas?

```
static public func getBalance(_ balance_label: String) -> Int {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? ""
    let balanceRef = db.collection("account").document(userId).collection("balance")
    balanceRef.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            return 0
        } else {
            guard let querySnapshot = querySnapshot else { return 0 }
            for document in querySnapshot.documents {
                print("document.data() is \(document.data())")
                guard let label = document.data()["label"] as? String else { continue }
                if label == balance_label {
                    guard let balance = document.data()["balance_amount"] as? Int else { return 0 }
                    return balance
                }
            }
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Asyncronicity again. `balanceRef.getDocuments()` is asyncronous and you cannot return a value from the closure to be returned by `getBalance`

Comment: That must be it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your return statements are inside the closure defined on line 5:

```
balanceRef.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in ... }
```

That closure's signature doesn't specify a return type so if I think that if you remove the values from the return statements inside that closure and then ensure that after the `getDocuments() {}` you explicitly return an `Int` you should satisfy the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The `getDocuments` is an asynchronous method. You cannot `return` values from an asynchronous closure. You will need to refactor this to use completion handler pattern.

```
static public func getBalance(_ balance_label: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? ""
    let balanceRef = db.collection("account").document(userId).collection("balance")
    balanceRef.getDocuments { querySnapshot, err in
        guard let querySnapshot = querySnapshot, err == nil else {
            print("Error getting documents:", err ?? "Unknown error")
            completionHandler(0)
            return
        }

        for document in querySnapshot.documents {
            print("document.data() is \(document.data())")
            if let label = document.data()["label"] as? String, label == balance_label {
                let balance = document.data()["balance_amount"] as? Int
                completionHandler(balance ?? 0)
                return
            }
        }
        completionHandler(0)
    }
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
Foo.getBalance(label) { value in
    // use `value` here
}

// but not here, because the above runs asynchronously
//
```